# Removing OS from Dual Boot computer, and recovering HD space.

Tags: dual-boot

I have a computer that dual boots Linux Mint, and Ubuntu, I am wondering what the best way would be to remove Linux Mint, then recovering the hard drive space that is resides in so that Ubuntu will be able to access it.

Comment: Could you please show the output of 'sudo fdisk -l' and note which partitions are used with Linux Mint (one root partition and one swap partition, most likely)?

Comment: No I can't as I am work and my computer is at home, I will try to get to it later tonight if I have time.

Comment: It is simple to do via GParted, as long as you understand what you are doing--I assume you do. But if removing the Mint partition disturbs your bootloader, you'll have to reinstall it, etc before you can boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps to claim space from Mint partition.

1. Login to Ubuntu
2. Start gparted: `sudo gparted`. If not available, then install it.
3. Find the Mint partition and format it

   Or delete it and create a new partition.
4. If Mint has modified (taken control of) your boot loader, then :

   1. Boot from live USB/CD for Ubuntu

      - I use the same version. I have no idea how different versions of 
        Ubuntu would work especially 32/64 bit differentiation.
   2. Open Terminal.
   3. If you don't know the drive where Ubuntu is installed, use 
      `sudo fdisk -l`, which will list partitions. Note down the one with 
      root. Boot will be indicated by a star (`*`). Assuming your root 
      (`/`) partition shows /dev/sdaX, where X is a number.
   4. Execute:

      ```
      sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
      sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
      sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
      sudo chroot /mnt
      ```
   5. Assuming you have only one HDD and it is sda, execute:

      ```
      grub-install /dev/sda # Note there is no X here
      ```
   6. Once it is installed unmount all

      ```
      sudo umount /mnt/dev
      sudo umount /mnt/proc
      sudo umount /mnt
      ```
5. Remove USB so you can boot from HDD, then reboot.

Comment: Great. I'm gonna use that as well.

Comment: sure :) just a note: once I deleted my Ubuntu partition instead of windows cause I was not paying proper attention :P

Comment: Happened to me too once, although it was on win.

Comment: Note that this applies to a BIOS/MBR system. Fixing the bootloader on a UEFI/GPT system is different.

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/301745) for UEFI/GPT.